# Converting String/Double to Int in Android

Tags: java, android

Hello new to android/Java,

I am using JSON to Parse values as strings and doubles. I am getting strings/doubles  such as "6503.04" or "12.3942" etc. I am looking to see if I can convert these strings into an integer and also doubles into integers. I just need to get rid of the decimals points in the easiest way possible. How can I make that happen?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: use int value = Integer.valueOf(yourString);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 double x = Double.parseDouble(your_string);
int y = (int) x;
```

y is going to have value of x with decimals cutted of.

Before casting to int you are able to floor or ceil the number if you want.

Don't forget that parsing functions usually throw an exception when your_string is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

//get the value from json as double then get the integer

```
Double number = jsonObject.getDouble('longitude')
int newNumber = number.intValue()
```